# Showing $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)}$ is analytic near $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

### Problem

> Show the function
>
> $$
> f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)}
> $$
>
> is an analytic about $x=0$.

---

### Try

We have

$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - \cdots }
$$

Letting $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $, we have

$$
a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 0, a_3 = 1/6, a_4 = 0, a_5 = 7/360, \cdots
$$

thus $f(x) = x - x^3/6 + \cdots$.

Now we have to decide if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is convergent near zero.

But I cannot see the rules of $a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots$, so how should I proceed?

---

It is known that

> Assume $f: = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ and $g:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ be convergent near zero with radius of convergence $\rho>0$.
>
> If $g(0) \neq 0$, we have

$$
\frac{f}{g} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n
$$

for some radius of convergence $\le \rho$. So relating this fact to my problem,

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x^2/3! + x^4/5! - \cdots }
$$

may be convergent with radius of convergence $\le \infty$, which is the radius of $x^2$(poylnomial) and $\sin(x)$

Comment: What exactly do you men by 'some radius $\leq \rho$'? Do you know that the radius is $>0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I meant "radius of convergence". Are they still equivocal?. Edited. Thanks

Comment: Note that $0$ is a removable singularity and numerator and denominator are both holomorphic, then done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - \cdots }=\frac{x}{1 - x^2/3! + x^4/5! - \cdots }.$

The nominator and the denominator are power series with radius of convergenc $= \infty$. The power series in the denominator is $ \ne 0$ at $x=0.$ Hence there is $ r>0$ such that

$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_nx^n$ for $|x|<r.$

We have $r= \pi$. Why ?

Comment: The point is whether $x$ can be cancelled in numerator and denominator for all $x\in\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac x {g(x)}$ where $g(x)=\frac {\sin\, x} x$ (for $x \neq 0$, $g(0)=1$). So what you have written as 'It is known that ....' immediately gives you the result.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not defined where $\sin x=0$. Elsewhere, it is the ratio of two analytic functions, hence it is analytic in $\mathbb R\setminus\{k\pi\}$.

Note that discussing analyticity at $x=0$ would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> A real function $f(x)$ is $R-analytic$ at some point $x_0$ if there exists an interval $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ s.t. $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$ valid in $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$.

It is not so hard to see that $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$ is the Taylor's coefficient.    Since $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=1$ which assures a removable singularity at $x=0$ *(though $a_0=f(0)$ is not explicitly defined in the question)*. On defining $f(0)=1$ you will get a nice series in  non-negative powers of $x$ valid in$(-π,π)$, which shows $f(x)$ is $R-analytic$ at $x=0$.